# AWS SDK Timeout through HTTPD Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, httpd

For "reasons," the application I am supporting connects to AWS S3 through an Apache HTTPD proxy.

When using either AWS Java SDK or AWSCLI to upload large files to S3 through a default HTTPD 2.4 proxy, CONNECT attempts are logged every 40 seconds, then the connection dies after 198-199 seconds.

No error is logged in Apache HTTPD. Just 4 CONNECT logs, each exactly 40 seconds apart.

The error in the AWS applications is:

`Max retries exceeded with url: <snip> (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')))`

I cannot find any configuration items in either AWS or HTTPD regarding multiple connections and timeouts.

1. Is the HTTPD proxy terminating the connection or is it the destination (S3)?
2. Is there any configuration for HTTPD I'm missing that would relate to multiple proxy connections?

Comment: Looks to me like your httpd proxy isn't accepting connections. Nothing else I can really say given there isn't much information provided. Try the proxy with something else, a web browser, curl, or similar.

Comment: The proxy is definitely accepting connections. Any upload that takes less than 198 seconds completes without issue. I'm able to browse through the proxy, including downloading large files without issue. However, uploading using AWS API/CLI consistently fails with "forcibly closed" after about 198 second, but only through the proxy (i.e. it's probably not an AWS S3 issue).

Comment: Use [S3 multipart upload](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/) with a chuck size suited for your upload speed. This is best practice, probably easier than trying to get Apache to do long running connections.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I agree. However, we need to ensure all files uploaded to S3 are encrypted. We are currently enforcing this using a bucket policy that checks x-amz-server-side-encryption. However, multi-part uploads does not set this when it uploads. We have the limit for multipart uploads set very high to avoid that right now. To set x-amz-server-side-encryption on each part of a multipart upload would require an application rewrite, which we cannot do. Perhaps there's a policy that would allow me to require aws:kms be set or x-amz-server-side-encryption be blank (to use default)?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought setting a header would require all that much work. I guess you'll need to wait for an Apache person to help with leaving connections open if you can't modify your application.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it requires much work, but the application is already deployed and there are funding and approval issues... We're working at a proper bucket policy, but it seems multipart uploads are sending an encryption header, even though it's set not to.